# wordpress custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

When adding a new post the custom fields from a previous post are showing as meta data for the new post. Is there some way to clear these fields when a new post is being created or is there possibly an issue with my installation?

Comment: Could your provide more information, like some sample code from the template file where you are generating the output for your custom fields? Check to see if you have it hard coded for a post.

Comment: this appears on when clicking on New Post in wordpress. there is no template code or plugin that is adding any information to the new post window. the custom fields dont actually exist in the db, well not by the ID used for them, but they are from other posts. deleting the fields on the new post window returns everything back to normal, but this problem does re-occur.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a list of *available* custom fields if you talking about custom fields list in the select box below post editor, otherwise it's impossible that other fields were copied from previous post without any plugin interaction.